# getActionBar returning null

Tags: android, null, android-actionbar

I have a activity

and I have added

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And I want to display home button on action bar.
Home button is from android predefined.

And I am calling this method

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But when I run the app, it gives that getActionBar retured `null`

Full code of activity is following

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    . setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });



    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Why getActionBar returning null? thats my question.

Comment: You need to use the `getSupportActionBar()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 0):

Use in Activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Use in fragment

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

instead of

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: On activity I am using `ViewPager` and I am using setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled on fragment. how can I do this then?